# Excluding parts but keeping everything in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, include

I have a document where I use `\includeonly` to only compile parts of it at a time. However I would still like the `Table of Contents` to display everything. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, compile twice with all `\includes` enabled and then say `\nofiles` in the preamble, using `\includeonly` at will. This way, the `toc` won't be regenerated and is frozen to the full state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\nofiles` will freeze (any!) generation of `.toc` etc. files:

Compile twice first with `%\includeonly` and then add `\nofiles` and remove the `%` in front of `\includeonly` to include the relevant parts at will.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents}{mychapter1.tex}
\chapter{First}
\section{First}
\subsection{First}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mychapter2.tex}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Second}
\subsection{Second}
\end{filecontents}

\includeonly{mychapter1}

\nofiles

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{mychapter1}

\include{mychapter2}

\end{document}
```